# Send Ctrl+Alt+Del+Del through radmin

Tags: windows-xp, keyboard-shortcuts, remote-control

I have radmin installed on my server, but I need to login as hidden user. In windows XP there is a login screen shortcut - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd>.
This shortcuts brings on a standart login window where both username and password may be entered manually.
How do I dispatch this shortcut from radmin?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Send Ctrl-Alt-Del` entry from the Remote Screen *window menu*. This feature will work in 'Full control' connection type. You can also use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd> hotkey for a quick sending.

<sub>[`Reference`](http://support.radmin.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/88/12/how-to-send-ctrl-alt-del)</sub>

Comment: I know about that. But I thought it executes server side - so presing one more <kbd>Del</kbd> won't help. But it did, I just had to be fast.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, try <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd>/<kbd>Insert</kbd>.  That is also a typical shortcut on remote apps.